# White text disappearing when printed from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, white

I am trying to print something that has a black background, but white text. It has a few different text squares.

Every time I try to print, one of the three text boxes disappears. I can see it on my print preview and on my artboard, but it will not print.

I’ve had this issue before where I would have to mess with the layers and send things to the front or back, but this is not the case.

I have done everything I could possibly think of. When I move one of the text boxes to the front and then the other two disappear when I print. If I move the other two text boxes to the front, or even try to group all three text boxes and one or two, respectively, just disappear when I print my page.

It’s not an issue of checking the attributes menu; I’ve done all that.

Comment: What happens if you convert all the text to outlines before printing?

Comment: Make certain white is not set to overprint in the Attributes Panel.

Comment: what do you mean by converting all text to the outlines? Do you mean group the text to the background? Sorry.. I'm new to Illustrator

Comment: Im trying to provide you with a screenshot of what I am trying to print & what I get. I have been trying to ungroup everything within the ad &then trying to move those elements above & below each other. it just wants to hide an element everytime I try to move one. so frustrating

Comment: May be due to masking... really impossible to tell without examining the file.. making this off-topic ultimately.

Comment: I am trying to provide you with a screenshot of what I am trying to get & what I am getting

Answer (score 1):

Check the "Attributes" panel while selecting the non printing text and see if has the "Overprint Fill" square checked. Then make a print or go to the go to the "Separations Preview" panel to review if it keeps disappearing.

Comment: I've checked the attributes panel & the overprint fill square is not checked. I may have figured my problem out, but i'm not sure yet

Comment: Share the solution.